# Show the data in firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I have a problem showing data in the firebase however my code works.

```
 import pyrebase
firebaseConfig={"apiKey": "AIzaSyDm2HeGl3bApix5KsbhI8NOjdwXkhNTaJM",
"authDomain": "trialauth-7eea1.firebaseapp.com",
"databaseURL": "https://trialauth-7eea1.firebaseio.com",
"projectId": "trialauth-7eea1",
 "storageBucket": "trialauth-7eea1.appspot.com",
 "messagingSenderId": "441088628124",
"appId": "1:441088628124:web:6fc6142f0e28275e2f2459",
"measurementId": "G-NKL8XN36NX"}
firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
db=firebase.database()
data={"age":20, "address":["new york", "los angeles"]}
print(db.push(data))
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you shared? So: when you run it, what doesn't work about it? Is there an error message?